# How can I confirm if/where/how Java 2D is using hardware acceleration for image rotations on Mac OS?

Tags: java, image, macos, rotation, java-2d

As a follow-up to  [Where is the time going with my ImageMagick rotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372096/where-is-the-time-going-with-my-imagemagick-rotations), I'd like to understand if/how/where the following Java code is making use of hardware acceleration on my Macbook Air running Java 6:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(10));
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
rotated = op.filter(image, null);
```

From browsing various SO questions, I gather this is going through the Java 2D library which in turn is going through an Apple-supplied JavaVM implementation.

Can someone provide guidance on to how I might determine this? (Note: My assumption is that it *is* making use of hardware acceleration because it can rotate a letter size, full-color 300 dpi image in about 50 milliseconds).

**Update #1:** I tried running the Java 2D trace option, but the lack of any trace output suggests that the above primitives aren't part of Java 2D or aren't considered "graphics primitives".

```
MacbookAir1:tmp palfvin$ java -Dsun.java2d.trace=log,timestamp,count,verbose MyApp foo.png
GraphicsPrimitive logging enabled
GraphicsPrimitive timetamps enabled
GraphicsPrimitive invocation counts enabled
GraphicsPrimitive trace output to System.err
MacbookAir1:tmp palfvin$
```

Comment: Short of running with [DTrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html), you might check the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-137037.html#Q_What_kinds_of_graphics_hardwar) where you would have seen `-Dsun.java2d.trace=[log[,timestamp]],[count],[out:<filename>],[help],[verbose]`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the suggestions. Will look at DTrace next, but see question update for experience with the second suggestion.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I assume Java 6 is using hardware acceleration, since Java 2D in Oracle's JRE 7 is [painfully slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108866/slow-java2d-bilinear-interpolation-in-java-7-on-mac-os-x).